# PhpStorm debugging, document roots and includes ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] not interpreted)

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

EDIT: I will edit this question properly later but this is NOT an Apache problem it is an IDE problem within PhpStorm. I have sorted all the problems and answered below.

I have been trying to sort things out for literally months on various machines. I have cleared the gremlins from my Apache setup by good magic I think (here if you want more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251175/virtual-host-not-working) .

Now everything seems to be working fine. I have various virtual hosts including `sane30` and `sane30.dev` which in a web browser behave as expected.

If I do an `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` in `sane30.dev/index.php` or `sane30/index.php` I get `C:/xampp/htdocs/sane30/`. If I do the same test with `localhost/sane30/index.php` I get `C:/xampp/htdocs/` - the page runs BUT any `include` or images or whatever are not found. All as expected I guess.

My real problem at the moment is debugging in PhpStorm.

A) I am really struggling to understand how to debug in PhpStorm - I am 100% convinced it will be mammothly helpful but I am finding it difficult to understand but also

B) I am having a nightmare getting PhpStorm to find the right document root consistently. Every time I hit debug it launches as `http://localhost/sane30/beta30/newForm.php` not `http://sane30/beta30/newForm.php` or `http://sane30.dev/beta30/newForm.php` which screws up all the `includes` and makes it impossible to debug. To make matters worse there seems to be something very random going on. I have tried changing many settings with little success.

So a) is anyone familiar with PhpStorm and able to advise me where to define `sane.dev` as the root server as opposed to `localhost`

and/or

b) can anyone help with a strategy to make all pages understand the same root despite how the are originally launched (sane30 or localhost)?

In `hosts` I have

```
127.0.0.1  sane30
127.0.0.1  sane30.dev
```

and in httpd-vhosts.conf I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sane30
ServerAlias sane30.dev *.sane30.dev
DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/sane30/
</VirtualHost>
```

if that is helpful.

Comment: *"Every time I hit debug it launches as http://localhost/..."* Screenshots please (as many as possible). I also want to see such URL there. If that is the URL then you have configured it like that yourself. If it would be IDE-generated then it would be different (a bit).

Comment: @LazyOne (nice name) sorted out the path problem which I will post as an answer. Thanks for the interest - now if you use PhpStorm and feel like  pointing me to a primer on debugging that would be great. // I am going to edit this answer and probably post the "How do I use the debugger" elsewhere. Think my trials could be useful to other PhpStormers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1) PhpStorm does NOT translate `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` so any use of this to make a path is doomed.

2) setting directories in PhpStorm.

I am not sure this HAS to be done but it seems to have worked for me.

In settings you need deployment:
[image]

There I set my root URL and used "In place" which seems to work fine.

Then on the Mapping tab I set up the relevant paths (this might have been OK but worth a check).

[image]

Finally two of the debugging hurdles I hit and for which I could not find any solutions here or Google.

"Frames are not available": I wasted an hour thinking this was a problem - it just means debug has nothing to report. If you look at the console it simply say "yippee it ran without incident" so if you have set breakpoints, variable watches or whatever - then you need to check what you are looking at!

I also wasted ages because the Frames tab in the debugger had disappeared (was not visible).

[image]

The solution could not be simpler but if you are a newb like me hope this save you time. Simply click the "Restore layout" button and voila.

[image]